# JavaScript - Slick Carousel showing 2 and 1/2 slides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with Slick carousel in JavaScript

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I want to show 2 slides plus part of the 3rd slide on the carousel, like in the picture below.

[image]

How do I achieve this effect?

Here is a Codepen of Slick in action

https://codepen.io/paveldominguez/pen/ElLfb

```
<section id="features" class="blue">
            <div class="content">
                
                
                
                
                <h2>Responsive Display</h2>
                <div class="slider responsive">
                    
                    <div>
                        <h3>1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        <iframe width="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ubGpDoyJvmI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>4</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>5</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>6</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>7</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>8</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>9</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h3>10</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is a good example, it could help you. https://codepen.io/ehsantl/pen/QKGroV
with this css:

```
.slider {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

js:

```
var settings = {
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  slide: '.slick-slideshow__slide',
  slidesToShow: 2.5,
  infinite: false,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
};
```

Comment: I cant get it to work. I wish slick just let you set "slidesToShow" to 2.5. Would be so easy. Thanks for your answer tho

Comment: "slidesToShow: 2.5 and make infinite: false" fixes it if you want to change your answer

Comment: i changed the answer. thanks for the feedback